# How do I halt the continuing in GDB

Tags: c, gdb

I'm pretty much using GDB for the first time.
I run

```
$ gdb
```

then I'm running

```
attach <mypid>
```

then I see that my process is stuck (which is probably ok). Now I want it to continue running, so I run

```
continue
```

and my process continues running
but from here I'm stuck if I want again to watch my current stack trace etc. I couldn't get out of continuing... I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> etc. but nothing worked for me... (was just a guess).

Comment: i tried also CTRL-C it didn't

Comment: What do you mean by stuck? An infinite loop? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702658/gdb-how-do-i-pause-during-loop-execution

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should interrupt the process that is attached by gdb.
Do not interrupt gdb itself.
Interrupt the process by either ctrl-c in the terminal in
which the process was started or send the process the SIGINT
by kill -2 procid. With procid the id of the process being attached.

Comment: Shame there isn't a way to do this from the host when using gdbserver/client.

Comment: Not wanting to state the obvious, but it'll only work if the program doesn't handle SIGINT. If there's a sigaddset frenzy in main() or some init()... ;)

Comment: This is hardly the best answer. You should not assume that the problem doesn't handle interruptions. The best answer should state how to gain interactivity with gdb (within gdb): "Control+C in the gdb process should bring you back to the command prompt."

Answer (score 9):

Control+C in the gdb process should bring you back to the command prompt.

Comment: ctrl-c does not work for me have a look please:

'
bash-3.00# gdb
GNU gdb 6.8
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i386-pc-solaris2.10".
(gdb) attach 4305
Attaching to process 4305
Retry #1:
Retry #2:


'

Comment: <pre>
Retry #3:
Retry #4:
[New LWP 1]
0xfef298b5 in ?? ()
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0x80477c8:
 eip = 0xfef298b5; saved eip 0xfef1b5d2
 Arglist at 0x80477c0, args:
 Locals at 0x80477c0, Previous frame's sp is 0x80477c8
 Saved registers:
  eip at 0x80477c4
(gdb) print
The history is empty.
(gdb) continue
Continuing.



^D
^C
quit


^C^C^C
^C

</pre>

Comment: how can i format this plz? i had this in separate lines how do i have it also in comments what i pasted in separate lines please?

Comment: You can't format (much) in comments. Edit it into your question.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a short [GDB tutorial](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/), and here's a [full GDB manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/).

The point of debugging is to inspect interesting/suspicious parts of the program. [Breakpoints](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html) allow you to stop execution at some source location, and [watchpoints](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) allow you to stop when interesting data changes.

Simple examples:

```
(gdb) break my_function
(gdb) cont
```

This will insert a breakpoint at the beginning of `my_function`, so when execution of the program enters the function the program will be suspended and you get GDB prompt back, and be able to [inspect program's state](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Data.html). Or you can [step](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html) through the code.

```
(gdb) watch my_var
(gdb) cont
```

Same, but now the program will be stopped at whatever location that modifies the value of `my_var`.

Shameless plug - here's a link to my [GDB presentation](http://www.fetissov.org/public/gdb/) at [NYC BSD User Group](http://www.nycbug.org). Hope this helps.

Comment: but i just wanted to pick a point in time of my own and at that point to examine the stack trace... and afterwards to continue the program, i didn't want breakpoints... in my case I want to examine the stack trace of the program at a time of my own.

Comment: OK, what does `info signal` says about `SIGINT`?

Comment: @Jas what possible use is it to randomly interrupt a running program to examine the stack trace? All you're going to find is that the code that is currently on the stack is the code that is running. Usually this is a loop waiting for user input. Ho hum.

Answer (score 0):

### interrupt

```
gdb> help interrupt
Interrupt the execution of the debugged program.
If non-stop mode is enabled, interrupt only the current thread,
otherwise all the threads in the program are stopped.  To 
interrupt all running threads in non-stop mode, use the -a option.
```

interrupt cmd also send `SIGINT` to debugged process.

```
gdb> info thread
Cannot execute this command while the target is running.
Use the "interrupt" command to stop the target
and then try again.

gdb> interrupt
[New Thread 27138.27266]
[New Thread 27138.27267]
[New Thread 27138.27268]
[New Thread 27138.27269]
[New Thread 27138.27270]

Thread 1 "loader" received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x0000007fb7c02e90 in nanosleep () from target:/system/lib64/libc.so
```